# Webpacker requires Node.js >= 8.16.0 and you are using 8.10.0

Tags: node.js, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, backend, web-development-server

I am trying to run ruby on rails in my ubuntu 18.04. But when I compile it, I recive this error
**Webpacker requires Node.js >= 8.16.0 and you are using 8.10.0** but I tried using **nvm npm** to change the version still [nodejs version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNtVA.png).Help me out to change this version.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by upgrading with Node Version Manager and not npm.

1. Start by updating the package repository with the command:

```
sudo apt update
```

2. Download the following dependencies by typing:

```
sudo apt install build-essential checkinstall libssl-dev
```

3. Install NVM using the curl command:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.35.1/install.sh | bash
```

4. Close and reopen the terminal.
5. Then, verify if you have successfully installed NVM:

```
nvm --version
```

check nvm version to update Node.js

6. Before upgrading Node.js, check which version you have running on the system:

```
nvm ls
```

7. Now you can check for newly available releases with:

```
nvm ls-remote
```

To see a list of all available Node.js versions

8. To install the latest version, use the nvm command with the specific Node.js version:

```
nvm install [version.number]
```

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version